# Is there a way to add range slicer to Excel worksheet for data filtering?

Tags: excel, controls, filtering

I'd like to add range slicers to an Excel worksheet for quick data filtering. However, I could not find such a control from Excel, and based on quick Googleing, it seems to be included in Power BI. I'd assume you can either get it from some (free) add-in or create it yourself.

Many thanks for anyone who can help on this!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add slicers in Excel. You just need to convert your data to a table first.

1. Select your data
2. Press ctrl + t or go to Insert -> Table.
3. Then select if your table has headers and click OK.

Now you will see the options to add slicers.

1. Still with your table selected (or any cell inside it), navigate to Insert -> Slicer.
2. Mark the column you want and it is done.

You can find a good explanation on this [link](https://www.educba.com/slicer-in-excel/). But fell free to reach out in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I'm familiar with how to add regular slicers that are poor for selecting numerical values from a large range. What I don't know and ask here is how to add *range slicers*. Like a slider; a knob that you can slide on a range line to select a value from within the range. Range here is a numerical range, with min and max values taken from the data in one column.

Comment: Got it. I am searching for an alternative, but I could not find so far.